# How to implement a Toast with mutableStateof<boolean> for 3sec in a horizontal image slider

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-toast, androidimageslider

```
@Composable
fun Sample() {

    Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
        HorizontalPager(
            count = 7,
            state = pagerState,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
        ) {
            Full1()
        }

        HorizontalPagerIndicator(
            pagerState = pagerState,
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
            activeColor = Utilities.activeColor,
            inactiveColor = Utilities.inactiveColor
        )
    }
}
```

This is the code where i have to implement.As i am new to this field so i didnt know how the code flow will work

This is the code where i have to implement the toast for 3 sec "timer started" in a image slider and after time passed it again show a toast of "time stopped"